# Possible to alias values clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following:

```
select 1 as user_id, 'A' as first_name union all values (2,'B'),(3,'C')
```

Is it possible to instead do something like:

```
VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C') AS (user_id,first_name)
```

Or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On option is to alias the table in a subselect, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')) tbl(user_id, first_name)
```

Both queries are 71 chars, so preference is up to you in terms of readability -- I prefer this one.

Comment: _"so preference is up to you..."_ - Sir, you're talking to yourself...

Comment: Is this not the normal way of using a *values* table constuctor, I've used this since always in sql server and postgres, as documented eg [like here](https://database.guide/postgresql-values-command-explained/)